# How can I get the names as a List<String> or Set<String> given the Enums?

Tags: java

For example:

```
    public enum Day {
        MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY,SUNDAY;
    }
```

Given the Enums `MONDAY`, `WEDNESDAY`, `SATURDAY`, I could get the List or Set in which the elements are `["monday", "wednesday", "saturday"]`. Any methods in Java? Or any other Util classes?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please go through [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of SO before posting a question to avoid down votes or worst - closures

Answer (score 8):

You can use the method `values()` of the enumeration type, it returns an array with the enumeration values:

```java
Day.values();
```

If you would like to transform the array to a list of strings, you simply need to do the following:

```java
Arrays.stream(Day.values()).map( (v) -> v.name()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This would return a `List<Day>`, not a `List<String>` as requested …

Comment: Thx for your comment, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

### Java 8

```
Arrays.stream(Day.values()).map( (v) -> v.name()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### Pre-Java 8

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for( Day day : Day.values() )  {
    list.add( day.name() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How functional the Java8 is! Are there any other solutions below Java8? It seems that only Java8 can solve this problem. Maybe it's time to upgrade to Java8!